# Search special characters in passwords and export those passwords to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract the passwords in which there are special characters and export those passwords into a new dataframe. The Dataframe is as shown below:

```
Password          
*jafad,gwu
klfcv[(+%
12qwe&rghj
bcnyfd254
abcdefghij
```

I have tried to extract the passwords in the following manner:

```
data = pd.read_excel("password.xlsx", names = ['Password'])
def SpecialChar():

    special = pd.Series(data['Password']).str.findall(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)')
    print(special)

SpecialChar()
```

But the query shows results as shown below:

```
[*,]
[{)+%]
[&]
[]
[]
```

How do I extract the passwords with special characters only in a different dataframe?

Expected Output:

```
Password
*jafad,gwu
klfcv[(+%
12qwe&rghj
```

Comment: Do you want `data[data['Password'].str.contains(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+')]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isalnum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isalnum.html) with inverting mask by `~` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = data[~data['Password'].str.isalnum()]
print (a)
     Password
0  *jafad,gwu
1   klfcv[(+%
2  12qwe&rghj
```

Or use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for mask, if some `NaN`s add parameter `na=False`:

```
a = data[data['Password'].str.contains(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', na=False)]
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd method, it throws a syntax error pointing to "na = False"

Answer (score 0):

Base on your own approach , change the `findall` to `contains`

```
def SpecialChar():

    special = data['Password'][pd.Series(data['Password']).str.contains(r'([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)')]
    print(special)

SpecialChar()
0    *jafad,gwu
1     klfcv[(+%
2    12qwe&rghj
```

Comment: It throws a warning and a value error ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: @SrinidhiPatil base on you example data, it work fine on my side , I will recommend Jez's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As another code, it is also possible to use Python's traditional regex matching method such as below. However, I also recommend jezrael code.

```python
import re
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"Password": ["*jafad,gwu",
                                  "klfcv[(+%",
                                  "12qwe&rghj",
                                  "bcnyfd254",
                                  "abcdefghij"]})
data.loc[data['Password'].apply(lambda x: bool(re.search(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', x)))]
# Out[36]: 
#      Password
# 0  *jafad,gwu
# 1   klfcv[(+%
# 2  12qwe&rghj
```